# How to write multiple conditions in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I understand we are able to write a condition in property as `ternary operator` as follows

```
onTap: textType == "birth"
                ? () {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                    showPicker(context, birthController,ref);
                  }
                : null,
```

but when it comes to multiple conditions, how can I rewrite the code like？ as the code shown below treated as syntax error.

```
onTap:
if (textType == "birth"){
 //do something
}else if(textType == "place"){
//do something
}else{
 return null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use nested ternary operators. It's sort of ugly, but it's how you do it.

Example: `myVar ? "hello" : myVar2 ? "hey" : "yo"`

This checks the first condition (`myVar`) then if that fails, checks the second condition (`myVar2`). You can also do actual checks here in place of just checking a boolean value. For example: `myVar == 14`

Alternatively, you can just call a function from your code, where you use if/else if/else etc. This is what I would recommend.

For example, call `getProperGreeting()` from your code, which would refer to:

```
String getProperGreeting() {
... <if else chain> ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and it became clear !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
onTap: textType == "birth" ? () {
     //do something when textType == "birth"
   } : textType == "place" ? () {
     //do something when textType == "place"
   } : () {
     //do something else
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment,  I didn't know this kind of expression is acceptable, and felt kind of `switch`! thank again!

Answer (score 1):

You wanna use custom method to handle onTap with condition

```
onTap: _onTapHandler
```

```
  void _onTapHandler() {
    if(textType=='birth'){
      //do something
      }else if(textType=='place'){
        //do something else
      }
      else if(textType == 'foo'){
        //bar
      }
  }
```

or use nested ternary operators as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,  and figured out  simple way to solve this problem !